# How to use selenium to get the CSS value of the test page?

Tags: css, selenium-rc

How to use selenium-rc to get the CSS value of the test page ???

for example: get the color of background or get the border size ??

environment: selenium-rc+vs2008+xp+c#

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using javascript. See [this link](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#executing-javascript-from-your-test) for details about executing javascript from your test.